# how to sharing and update data between controller with service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

Now I am trying sharing data between controllers with factory. what I want is whenever I update my input value in controlA the value in controlB will be updated. Would you please point out where is my problem?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('share', function() {
    return {
        user: {}
    };
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, share) {
    $scope.user = {
        name: 'lin'
    };
    share.user.name = $scope.user.name;
    console.log(share.user.name);
})
.controller('linctr', function($scope, share) {
    $scope.super = {
        name: share.user.name
    };
});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="user.name" />    
</div>
<div ng-controller='linctr'>
    <div>{{super.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second controller use:

```
.controller('linctr', function($scope, share) {
    $scope.super = share.user;            
});
```

In this case `$scope.super` points to the same object as `share.user`. Otherwise when you do

```
$scope.super = { 
    name: share.user.name
};
```

`super` has no connection to `share.user` object, it just assigns primitive value of the its property `name`.

Comment: I just added $watch in controllerA,then it works!$scope.$watch('user.name',function(newv,oldv){
     share.user.name=newv; 
        console.log(share.user.name);   });     
})

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to advise $watch. Or another approach is to use `share.user = $scope.user;` in the first controller. http://plnkr.co/edit/S2vdNVFOT6BkFSEJuLQK?p=preview

Comment: But you are right, I should point to object instead of property.Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: It's better to avoid additional watchers for performance sake. So if you can use object references it's more natural for javascript, as it works very fast.

Comment: I see it, Thank you very much for helping me out. it is real helpful!