# How to insert new row into table from child controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have table. When I want to insert new row then it will open new dialog window, through that window I insert row into table.

This new dialog window has child controller **addNewTaskCtrl**,In This dialog there is a form when I click add button then It will insert data into table. I tried but no able to connect ng-model of child with parent, please [SEE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kJNM4eOlW2nWA2LnMrgz?p=preview). **Please see button ADD Task.**

I also tried to insert new row into table **without using any child controller**, please see the,  [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCAkgK9PkuqHvrMNWnqY?p=preview), But didn't succeeded. 
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>ToDo API Client Demo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tasksCtrl">
  <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">ToDo API Client Demo</a>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div>

         <table class="table table-striped">
             <tr><td style="width: 1px;"></td><td><b>Task</b></td><td><b>Options</b></td></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="visible: done" class="label label-success">Done</span>
                    <span data-bind="visible: !done()" class="label label-important">In Progress</span>
                </td>
            <td>{{task.title}}</td>
            <td>{{task.description}}</td>
                        <td>  <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" ng-click="editTask(task)">Edit</a></td>
                <td>  <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-ng-click="removeRow(task)">Delete</a></td>

                <td>
                    <span data-bind="visible: done">
                          <button data-bind="click: $parent.markInProgress" class="btn">Mark In Progress</button>
                    </span>
                </td>
                        <td>
                     <span data-bind="visible: !done()">
                          <button data-bind="click: $parent.markDone" class="btn">Mark Done</button>
                     </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>

            <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" ng-click="editTask(task)">Add Task</a>
  </div>
  <div id="modal" role="dialog" class="modal hide fade">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-header">
                Task Dialog
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="txtName"></label> 
                <input type="text"  ng-model="selectedTask.title" />
                <input type="text"  ng-model="selectedTask.description" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveTask()" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div id="add" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="=1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addDialogLabel" aria-hidden="true"  ng-controller="addNewTaskCtrl">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="addDialogLabel">Add Task</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputTask">Task</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="inputTask" ng-model="$parent.task" placeholder="Task title" style="width: 150px;"><br />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputDescription">Description</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="inputDescription" ng-model="$parent.description" placeholder="Description" style="width: 300px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"> 
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="addNewTask()">Add Task</a>
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>


   <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('tasksCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("data.json")
        //$http.get("/todo/api/v1.0/tasks")
        .success(function(response) {
          console.log(response.tasks)
          $scope.tasks = response.tasks;
        });

        $scope.editTask=function(task) {
            $scope.selectedTask = task;
        };
        $scope.removeRow = function (task) {
            $scope.tasks.splice(task, 1);
        };

    });
    app.controller('addNewTaskCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.addNewTask=function(){
            var task;
        }
    }]);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Create an object that is passed to both controllers  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534822/how-to-sharing-and-update-data-between-controller-with-service-in-angularjs)
2. Broadcast the change from the child controller and watch for it in the parent controller by passing in the $rootscope.

So in your addCntrl:

```
    $rootScope.$broadcast("addedTask", newTask);
```

And in your tasksCntrl

```
    $scope.$on('addedTask', function(newTask){//handle stuff });
```

Hope this helps.